# Greenrobot's EventBus performance drawbacks

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I have been using [Greenrobot's Eventbus](https://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/) for it's simplicity 
for a while. I wonder if there is a performance loss if I use it in a scenario where I quite often post an event(4 times a second), and there is multiple recipients of the event, instead of using observer pattern.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Well if you refer to [EventBus 3](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)  which relies on APT-generated source code, no

Comment: "specifically optimized for high performance", yes I had read this. But still I'm not sure if this is still valid in high frequencies of event posts,

Comment: Sorry you are right "EventBus is optimized for performance. We will release extensive benchmark results (and a benchmark app) soon. For now, we can say that posting events is around 77,000 "

Comment: You will have to determine that for yourself. Perhaps there is something unique to how you are doing things that will be dramatically worse for EventBus than normal. In general, there should not be a noticeable between EventBus and something else, particularly if the "something else" is doing all the same sorts of stuff that EventBus does (e.g., weak/soft references).

Comment: It's generated source code, so there is no reflection. Afterwards it's worth checking what kind of code is generated based on your annotations.